# How to compensate MySQL TIMESTAMPDIFF for overflow

Tags: mysql, timestampdiff

I am using the MySQL `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` function to calculate the difference in months between two dates, but there is a problem with overflow.

Say I have a date, and I use MySQL to calculate the same date 1 month later:

`select DATE_ADD('2018-10-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` returns `2018-11-30`

So, now I have two dates, 2018-10-31 and 2018-11-30.

Now I would like to calculate the interval in months between those dates, but

`select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2018-10-31', '2018-11-30')` returns `0`, because of the number of days in November that DATE_ADD() adjusts for.

So, given two dates, which are calculated as above with DATE_ADD() and an interval of *n* months, is it possible to use either TIMESTAMPDIFF() or a different function to calculate *n*?

Comment: For now I am using `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, $date1, DATE_ADD($date2, INTERVAL 3 DAY))` which looks ugly but seems to work well.

Comment: What happens if you use timestampadd() instead of date_add()?

Comment: Same thing. Even then: the problem is in getting the _difference_ in months. The two dates are a given. I mention DATE_ADD() here only to show how they are related.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that you can use is to check the difference between days of the two dates. In this case, you would have 30 days, so you might consider it a month or less apart. In [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) there are some examples where one-month validation is described between periods of more than 31 days.

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,'2018-10-31','2018-11-30');
Result: 30
```

Comment: Yes, that would work when the dates are one month apart, but it doesn't work when comparing, say 2012-01-31 and 2019-02-28.

Comment: Actually, with the right division this could work quite well: `ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2012-01-31', '2112-01-31') / 30.4375)` . The value 30.4375 is the average number of days per month when taking into account there's one leap day every four years.

Comment: I think about do this. But you never can take a period less than zero. This dates ('2018-10-31', '2018-11-15') never will return zero.